# Grafana in Docker: not all Environment variables are transferred to grafana.ini

Tags: docker, grafana

I have quite a weird problem and I'm really not sure where it comes from. I'm trying to run a Grafana inside a Docker Container and want to set some grafana.ini values through Environment Variables in the Docker run Command.

```
docker run -d -v grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana -e "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=123456" -e "GF_USERS_DEFAULT_THEME=light" --name=grafana -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
```

The default Theme gets changed as wanted, the admin_password stays the same. I've checked for typos like a million times and could not find one. I've tried with '123456' and without, all with the same result. Is there a reason why I can't change this value?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could it be that you run grafana before and it already created the admin user? In such a case it may or may not replace it with your env var. Perhaps trying to do a fresh/clean install and see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#admin_password

> The password of the default Grafana Admin. Set once on first-run.

Please note the last sentence = it is used only on first run. It won't change admin password if you already changed admin password before and that new password is stored in the database.